How do I remove the space in the icon of push notification in android flutter

How do I remove the white space inside the circle

I recently implemented an adaptive app icon for my application in flutter, and it functions perfectly when displayed as the app icon on the device's home screen and app drawer. but i've encountered an issue with the icon's appearance in push notifications. The icon have a white space around it

In second image, Why both icons are different?
